# How to convert bytes into a UIImage in Swift?

Tags: swift, uiimage, uikit

I am reading the bytes information from my Firebase Database. On Firebase, the image appears as

```
iVBORw0kGg...
```

but when I read it in Xcode, it appears as

```
ffd8ffe0 00104a46 49460001 01000001 00010000 ffdb0043 00030202 02020203 02020203 03030304 06040404 04040806 06050609 080a0a09 0809090a 0c0f0c0a 0b0e0b09...
```

I'm not sure what type of data this is and how to convert it to a UIImage

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624106-init ?

Comment: what is your object type?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the bytes stored in a `Data` type, you can use UIImage's initializer directly with it.

```swift
var imageData: Data // let's assume that imageData has all the the bytes already
var image = UIImage(data: imageData)
```